# MaterializeCSS collapsible with IMAGE

Tags: css, image, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCSS and I'm looking to add and image inside of the "collapsible-body" of a Collapsible element... but it doesn't shows up.
It's possible to do what i'm trying some way? Maybe with CSS or JS?

here is my code:

```
<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <img href="https://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg"><!-- Example image -->
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and ofcourse the JS to initialize the collapsible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images use a SRC attribute, not HREF:

```
<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First</div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <img src="https://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg"><!-- Example image -->
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: omg!  I don't know why did I made this mistake... maybe some ctrl+c and ctrl+v unconscious

Thanks a lot!!